# I don't know how to setup automail

Tags: python, automation, auto-responder

I want to make a program in Python where is someone transfers money to my bankaccount,
i sent them a confirmation mail.
I don't know where to start and don't know how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/) provides such service. It has a free tier too. You can use it either posting request with `requests.post` or using pypi package [here](https://pypi.org/project/mailjet-rest/). The API documentation is also [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/).

As you may guess this is only for the mail service you asked. If the money transfer is a serious job, then the back end, transactions etc. requires some experience in that field.